# can i pass array that contain dictionary object into async map

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules

```
function(req, res, next) {  
    var products = [ 
        { id: 1, userid: 12, quntity: 12, productid: 15 }, 
        { id: 2, userid: 12, quntity: 8, productid: 16 } 
    ];    
    console.log("------1.here-----");
    // async MAP pass products array in it.. 
    async.map(products, upProduct, function(err, result) {
        console.log("------3.here-----");
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(result);                
    });
    function upProduct(cb) {          
        console.log("------2.here-----");      
        cb(null, products);
    }   
});
},
```

I can have a console.log 2.here but not get console.log 3.here 
can you give me suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code ,

```
function(req, res, next) {
            var products = JSON.parse(req.body.products);

            console.log("------1.here-----");
            // async MAP pass products array in it.. 

             function upProduct(obj,cb){               
                cb(null,products);
            } 
            async.map(products,upProduct,function(err, result){
                console.log("------3.here-----");
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(result);                
            });            
}
```